# C# Getting value from results view

Tags: c#

I am trying to use a value from a array returned from a API. The returned data is in the screenshot. [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImSGl.jpg)

Problem is when I try to use one of the values with `var test = result[0].ID;` I get a exception. The exception is not very helpful, it just says "incorrect value"

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks

Comment: What type of object you should use in view ? is it view model ? I see ComObject in that picture.

Comment: Does `result` have any other properties?

Comment: The documentation says I should get 3 properties - https://www.m-files.com/api/documentation/latest/MFilesAPI~ValueListItemSearchResults_members.html. But I only get "Count" and "More Results". From the looks of it the missing "item" is what I need. Why would I not be able to see it?

Comment: Such dynamic binding is not allowed you should serialize and convert data API to the modal class and then you will be able to access it